# How many types of Vaishnava Charama Shloka(s) exist?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, sharanagati

Charama means peak or climax, the Shloka which is given by Bhagwan as a climax to a great Dialogue and contains essence of Sharanagati(to he Lotus feet of Shriman Narayana) like BG 18.66.

Now there are various Charma Shlokas the most famous Shloka is from Bhagwad Gita.

> सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज।
>
> अहं त्वा सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुचः।।18.66।।
>
> Abandon all varieties of Dharma, and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear. [BG 18.66](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-66/)
>
> Relinquishing all Dharma means the complete relinquishment of the sense of agency, possessiveness, fruits etc,. while practising of Karma Yoga, Jnana Yoga and Bhakti Yoga in the instructed way, and the realising of Me as the agent and object of worship namely the means and the end.

Question : **How many types of Vaishnava Charma Shlokas are listed in Scriptures**

Comment: Which scriptures say that this sloka is a "vaishnava charama sloka"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the Charama Shlokas listed by the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Chinna Jeeyar Swami in [this web page](http://jetuk.org/2016/01/04/charama-slokas/):

> SRI:RA:MA CHARAMA SLO:KAM
>   sakrude:va prapanna:ya thava:smi:thi cha ya:chathe: |
>   abhayam sarvabhu:the:bhyo: dada:mye:thad vratham mama ||
>   mithrabha:ve:na sampraptham na thyaje:yam katthamchana |
>   do:sho: yadyapi thasya sya:th satha: me:tha dagarhitham ||
>
> SI:THA: CHARAMA SLO:KAM
>   pa:pa:na:m va subha:na:m va: vadha:rha:na:m plavamgama! |
>   ka:ryam karuna ma:rye:na na kaschin na:apara:dhyathi ||
>
> VARA:HA CHARAMA SLO:KAM
>   stthithe: manasi susvastthe: sari:re: sathi yo: naraha |
>   dha:thusa:mye: stthithe: smartha: visvaru:pam cha ma:majam ||
>   thathastham mriyama:nam thu ka:shta pa:sha:na sannibham |
>   aham smara:mi madbhaktham naya:mi parama:m gathim ||
>
> SRI: NA:RASIMHA CHARAMA SLO:KAM
>   sathyam bravi:mi manuja:ha svayamu:rdhva bahuhu
>   yo: ma:m muku:nda narasimha jana:rdane:thi |
>   ji:van japathynu dinam marane: runi:va
>   pa:sha:na ka:shta sadru:sa:ya dada:mi mukthim ||
>
> SRI:RANGA CHARAMA SLO:KAM
>   Ma:me:va:anusmarasva thvam thva:maham samsmara:mi cha |
>   Upa:ya mapavargasya rahasya mapi me: srunu ||
>   Sarva karma:ni santhyajya sarva karma phala:ni cha |
>   Saranam ma:m prapdyasva sarva bandha vimukthaye: ||
>
> SRI: SUDARSANA CHARAMA SLO:KAM
>   Sudarsana! Maha:jva:la! Ko:ti su:rya samaprabha! |
>   Agjnya:na:ndhasya me: de:va vishno:rma:rgam pradarsaya ||
>
> SRI: PA:NCHAJANYA CHARAMA SLO:KAM
>   Pa:nchajanya nijadhva:na dhvastha pa:thaka samchaya |
>   Pa:hi ma:m pa:pinam gho:ra samsa:ra:rnava pa:thinam ||

The Rama Charama Shloka is [chapter 18 verse 33](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga18/yuddhasans18.htm#Verse38) of the Yuddha Kanda of the Ramayana.  And the Sita Charama Shloka is [chapter 113 verse 46](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga113/yuddhasans113.htm#Verse51) of the Yuddha Kanda of the Ramayana.  I'm pretty sure the Varaha Charama Shloka is from a dialogue between Varaha and Bhumidevi in the Varaha Purana.  The Panchajanya and Sudarshana Charama Shlokas are chanted when metal brands of the Shankha and Chakra are placed on the shoulders during Samashrayanam, the initiation ritual into Pancharatra, so they're probably from the Pancharatra Agamas.  I'm not sure where the rest are from, but I can keep looking.